# How do I manipulate databases in excel through sqlite or transfer databases from one to another (both from and to excel and sqlite)?

Tags: excel, sqlite

I have just recently started using sqlite and most of my work had been previously done in excel or SPSS. I would like to know if there is a solution which allows me to open a file format from one of these programs into the other two e.g. open a sqlite file in spss/excel or opening an spss file in sqlite.

Much appreciated!

Comment: If you export your spreadsheet as a CSV file, you can easily import it into a sqlite table. See https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import (You can also export a table as CSV and then import that into a spreadsheet)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! The previous recommendations I had gotten were much more complicated, and guided me towards downloading ODBC software etc.                                                I appreciate the contribution!